# How to write search query with multiple filter inputs in asp.net web form for ms sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL Query for Advance search form shown as Image below.

I wrote this partial sql query but i cant make it work correctly as it also get syntax error if user select second check-box and leaves the first check-box.

```
strSql = "SELECT ArticleID, ArticleTitle, ArticleDesc, ArticlePublishDate FROM art_Articles WHERE ";
strSql += "( ArticleVisible = 1 AND ArticleActive =1 AND LanguageID =" + LangID +" )";
strSql += " AND ";
strSql += " ( ";

if (cbArchiveTitle.Checked)
{ strSql += "  ArticleTitle LIKE N'%" + search + "%'  "; }
if (cbArchiveDesc.Checked)
{ strSql += " OR ArticleDesc LIKE N'%" + search + "%'  "; }
if (cbArchiveSummary.Checked)
{ strSql += " OR ArticleBodyDesc LIKE N'%" + search + "%'  "; }

strSql += ")";
```

[image: Advanced Search Form]
If i design my query something like this

```
 SELECT ArticleID, ArticleTitle, ArticleDesc, ArticlePublishDate FROM art_Articles WHERE 
 ( ArticleVisible = 1 AND ArticleActive =1 AND LanguageID =1 ) AND  
 (   ArticleTitle LIKE N'%Jobs%'   OR ArticleDesc LIKE N'%%'  )
```

And pass null value to fields which are not selected then i got all the row selected.

I would appreciate any help in designing this query to work for the form as show in the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add little trick to you code to resolve the issue with not selected first check box:

```
strSql = "SELECT ArticleID, ArticleTitle, ArticleDesc, ArticlePublishDate FROM 

art_Articles WHERE ";
strSql += "( ArticleVisible = 1 AND ArticleActive =1 AND LanguageID =" + LangID +" )";
strSql += " AND ";
strSql += " ( 0 = 1 ";

if (cbArchiveTitle.Checked)
{ strSql += " OR ArticleTitle LIKE N'%" + search + "%'  "; }
if (cbArchiveDesc.Checked)
{ strSql += " OR ArticleDesc LIKE N'%" + search + "%'  "; }
if (cbArchiveSummary.Checked)
{ strSql += " OR ArticleBodyDesc LIKE N'%" + search + "%'  "; }

strSql += ")";
```

But in general it's not good approach to compose SQL statement in this way. You can consider to use either technologies like [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx) or at least some query builder like [SelectQueryBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S)

Comment: SelectQueryBuilder Seems like an option i also did it by using a little trick             if (cbArchiveTitle.Checked)
            { strSql += " ArticleTitle LIKE N'%" + search + "%'  "; }
            else
            { strSql += " ArticleTitle NOT LIKE N'%%'  "; }